# How do I regain my source after gcc -o mistake order

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I run "gcc -o program.c program" instead of "gcc program.c -o program" by mistake and now I lost my source (program.c). Is there any solution to regain my source or it is definitely lost?

Comment: If you don't have the source backed up anywhere, it's lost.  You can't recover the original source code from the compiled code.  There *are* tools that can take compiled code and produce an equivalent source (decompilers), but the generated source code won't be the same as the original, and may not be very readable.

Comment: This is a sad tale indeed. Your story will be told for the years to come.

Comment: @SanchkeDellowar come, come, we all have made these kind of terrible mistakes, it is part of the journey of becoming a great coder.

Comment: If you have the source code stored on some repository, you can check it out again.

Comment: a strong argument for using some kind of configuration control to keep backups of important files.

Answer (score 2):

No. It is lost, the OS overwrote your source code file.

Unless you have a backup, it is gone.

To prevent that from happening in the future, you could use `make`:

```
~$ make program
```